# Google Fusion table API for Insert and Update Columns

Tags: python, google-api, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to update my existing fusion table as it did in given python [Scripts](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/python) . It works for  method "GET" but it does not work for methods " PUT" and "POST". My URL request function is:

```
mport urllib2, urllib, simplejson, sys, httplib 

def runRequest(method, url, data=None, headers=None):

   request = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.googleapis.com")

   if data and headers: 
       request.request(method, url, data, headers)
   else: 
       request.request(method, url)

   response = request.getresponse()

   response = response.read()

   return response
```

I defined

> getColumns and insertColumn as:

```
def getColumns():
     print "GET COLUMNS"
     runRequest(
      "GET",
      "/fusiontables/v2/tables/%s/columns/%s" % \
        (tableid,  params))

  def insertColumn(name, data_type):
    print "Insert Column"
    data = '''{
    "tableId": %s,
      "name": %s,
      "type":%s
    }''' % (tableid, name, data_type)
    response = runRequest(
      "POST",
      "/fusiontables/v2/tables/%s/columns%s" % \
       (tableid, params), data, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
    json_response = simplejson.loads(response)
    print json_response
```

getColumn() method looks fine:

```
GET COLUMNS 

200 OK 
{  "kind": "fusiontables#columnList", 

 "totalItems": 28,  "items": [   {    "kind": "fusiontables#column",   
 "columnId": 0,    "name": "VDC",    "type": "STRING",   
 "formatPattern": "NONE",    "validateData": false   }}
```

I got the following error from insertColumn() method:

```
Insert Column
400 Bad Request
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

I think this is due to bad runRequest() method or httpconnection is not working well. Do you have any suggestion for it?. Is there any alternative way to solve this?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a good place to start.

> Parse Error

If you actually check the data output you'll find that it's not valid JSON.

```
tableid, name, data_type = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
data = '''{
"tableId": %s,
  "name": %s,
  "type":%s
}''' % (tableid, name, data_type)
print data
```

> '{
>       "tableId": foo,
>         "name": bar,
>         "type": baz
>   }'

String values need to have quotations around them. A better version would be something like this.

```
tableid, name, data_type = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
data = {
"tableId": tableid,
  "name": name,
  "type": data_type
}
print simplejson.dumps(data)
```

> {"type": "baz", "tableId": "foo", "name": "bar"}